# Encode form array elements into JSON using only JS or other client side libs

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, serialization

Im working on a joomla component and its not handling the serialization of my form data the way I need it to, so my solution is going to be to create a hidden textarea and populate it with the json data that is created as the form is filled out on the client side then just submit the text area.

```
  <input type="text" name="jform[work_experience][]employer"><input type="text" name="jform[work_experience][]position"><br/>
  <input type="text" name="jform[work_experience][]employer"><input type="text" name="jform[work_experience][]position"><br/>
  <input type="text" name="jform[work_experience][]employer"><input type="text" name="jform[work_experience][]position"><br/>
```

Imagine my form looks like this where the number of "rows" are dynamic, depending on how many the user needs. I would then like to serialize this into a JSON string that looks something like:

```
[
  {
    "employer": "apple",
    "position": "contract killer"
  },
  {
    "employer": "microsoft",
    "position": "bathroom attendant"
  },
  {
    "employer": "samsung",
    "position": "window washer"
  }
]
```

If I need to rename the fields to get the proper structure so be it.

Is there a jQuery function that would allow me to take `jform[work_experience]` and spit out a json string?

Comment: JSON.stringify( __YOUR_JAVASCRIPT_OBJECT_OR_ARRAY__ ) returns json

Comment: @25r43q I also read `.serializeArray()` I guess the question then is how do I target just these fields as an object that can be used in these functions. I forgot to mention that `jform` has other elements that I wish to ignore.

Comment: I could submit an example if its ok to change the datastructure and markup. But Im not sure how locked in you are in the current setup

Comment: @25r43q The json format I am semi locked into, only as that is how I would prefer it to look to still maintain some human readability, the form naming convention not so much

Comment: @25r43q especially since I guess i am talking about only submitting the final json string i guess the form really doesn't matter at all anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go, I added data-type to select stuff easier. And it uses native JS so you shouldnt have to worry about collisions with frameworks or libs. I also assume the fields come in tandem.

```
<form id="uniqueId">
    <input type="text" name="jform[work_experience][]employer" data-type="employer" value="apple">
    <input type="text" name="jform[work_experience][]position" data-type="position" value="contract killer"><br/>

    <input type="text" name="jform[work_experience][]employer" data-type="employer" value="apples">
    <input type="text" name="jform[work_experience][]position" data-type="position" value="Designer"><br/>

    <input type="text" name="jform[work_experience][]employer" data-type="employer" value="appe">
    <input type="text" name="jform[work_experience][]position" data-type="position" value="Sales rep"><br/>

</form>
```

JS:

```
var inputFields = document.querySelectorAll( '#uniqueId input' );
var dataObject = [];
for( var x = 0 ; x < inputFields.length ; x++ ){
    if( inputFields[ x ].dataset.type === "employer" ){
        var current = {};
        current.employer = inputFields[ x ].value;
        current.position = inputFields[ x + 1 ].value;
        dataObject.push( current );
        x++;    //skip check for next input
    }
}
//verify that the object holds data. The loop assumes 
//that employer and position come in tandem
console.log( JSON.stringify( dataObject ));
```

Outputs:

```
[{
        "employer": "apple",
        "position": "contract killer"
}, {
        "employer": "apples",
        "position": "Designer"
}, {
        "employer": "appe",
        "position": "Sales rep"
}]
```

EDIT: Fixed dataformat :)

Comment: Brilliant, i figured it was going to come down to iteration, I was just hoping there was a more direct route, I guess my issue was my misconception that the serializer does not see a multi-dimensional array as nested objects.

Comment: That is a misconception that I shared before I actually got down to use it properly. But most selectors or "direct" methods do iterate through data as well. And to be honest, simple for loops like this in javascript are so fast that no normal person would ever have to worry about the speed.

Comment: I'm assuming that using `#unique input[name^="jform[work_experience]]"` will work as well for my selector since the form has other input elements too.

Comment: I didnt try since I dont know how the jform[components] will render. But good luck anyways :)

Comment: Given that I had to iterate the data anyway and there was no simple function for what I wanted, I just moved this into php; `        $jobs = array();

        for($i = 0; $i < count($data['work_experience']); $i += 2)
        {
            $job = new stdClass();
            $job->Employer = $data['work_experience'][$i];
            $job->Position = $data['work_experience'][$i+1];
            $jobs[] = $job;
        }`